# Determine which TLS version is used by default (cURL)

Tags: curl

I have 2 servers that both run `curl 7.29.0` and `CentOS 7`. However, when I run the following command I get 2 different results:

```
curl https://tlstest.paypal.com
```

1. `PayPal_Connection_OK`
2. `ERROR! Connection is using TLS version lesser than 1.2. Please use TLS1.2`

Why does one server default to a TLSv1.2 connection and the other does not?

(I know I can force it with `--tlsv1.2` if I wanted to)

Comment: It might be a difference in patchlevel - Just checking the version a program reports is [not sufficient](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting/?sc_cid=3093) to determine it's patchlevel, check with for instance `rpm -qi curl` for differences in the Release

Comment: Ok, so I see that the values for release do vary. Would it be safe to assume this is the reason behind the 2 results?

Comment: That would be a *likely* cause. - `rpm -qa --last | less` will show the most recent packages that were installed and unless you regularly install additional new software, that is a good indication if a system gets security (regular) updates or not

Comment: Thank you @HBruijn, I appreciate your time and assistance.

Comment: Specifically, this was addressed in release number 25. So `libcurl-7.29.0-25` onwards will work fine`  (more info [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento/magento-paypal-libcurl-and-redhat-crazy-together))

Answer (score 1):

> Why does one server default to a TLSv1.2 connection and the other does not?

By default, `curl` will negotiate with the server, and will use the highest version that both `curl` and the server support. So if the connection uses different TLS versions, you likely have different versions of `curl` on the servers. As you write that the version reported by curl is the same, you should also check the version of "libcurl", the shared library that is used by `curl` - this might also be different.

Most likely one of the servers uses a fairly old version of `curl` or libcurl - curl has supported TLS 1.3 since 2016 (v7.52, I believe), and TLS 1.2 since 2012 (v7.28).

> I have 2 servers that both run curl 7.29.0 and CentOS 7.

Note that curl 7.29 is fairly old (released February 2013), so an upgrade is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps resolved my problem:

1. Update the following 3 packages:

`sudo yum update curl libcurl nss`

2. Restart nginx/apache*

`sudo service nginx restart`

`sudo service hhvm restart`

*Replace these with relevant services (e.g. apache, php-fpm, etc...)